# Custom keyboard layout in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to add a custom software keyboard layout to my Kubuntu 22.04 machine.
I have copied and adapted a layout definition file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.
Now [the instructions I've](https://www.kavalier.tv/blog/custom-keyboard-layout-for-coding-on-ubuntu-linux) found recommend as a next step to edit the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` - however, for me, there is no such file.

So, how do I proceed? How do I make sure my OS "knows" the new custom keyboard layout file and it becomes selectable in keyboard settings?

Comment: That's odd. Try: `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data`